# FFMPEG Stream to network port

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, video, streaming

I am searching around for 2 days but didn't find a solution.

Is it possible to stream a video to a local network port with ffmpeg?

My goal would be, to capture a remote stream, convert it and send it to my local port in real time.
The stuff should be something like a plain .mp4 stream that someone could catch and playback in a client.

The idea is to reduce network traffic and cpu power to watch the stream.

EDIT: Because the community bot wants a clear question.
Is it possible to stream a video with ffmpeg to a local network port.
It does not have to contain any data about the type or codec, it should be just a simple network stream of bytes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: assuming you just want to send the stream to another machine as udp, try "ffmpeg -i input -f format udp://<IP_address>:<port_number>

Comment: @Paul i will catch an online live stream, convert it. But this work has to be done on a server, so that multiple client can get the converted stream. But if ffmpeg only sends traffic on a peer to peer basis, i am gooing and try something different

Comment: @yuki, to send it to multiple clients on the same network, simply use a multicast IP address (239.x.x.x) in the command above, and instruct all the clients to listen to that address.

Comment: @Paul how am i joining a multicast group is a never solved mystery in my case. But i am using different networks in my home which would break this idea.

Comment: @yuki, if your router is multicast capable it should still work (assuming your networks are connected through that router) but you need to add ?ttl=32 to the udp string: udp://239.0.0.0:1234?ttl=32. Joining a multicast group happens automatically by listening to that address on the client. For instance, ffmpeg -i udp://239.0.0.0:1234